# What is wrong with substituting a constant in a system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, substitution

Imagine that I have the following system of equations:

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x + 2 &= 3 \\
y - 5 &= 3
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

The solution (x=1, y=8) of this equation is trivial (equations do not even depend on each other).

But imagine that to solve this system I do the following:

1. I note that both: x+2 and y-5 equal 3
2. I do the substitution: x+2 = y-5
3. I arrive at the solution: y-x=7

This solution includes the correct solution of (x=1, y=8), but generally is not correct.

**So my question is:** Is it correct to do a substitution like this? If not, what exactly makes it wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: It is correct but you need to keep 2 equations. The problem arised when you dropped one.

Comment: I don't understand. You do $$\begin{cases}x+2=3\\ y-5=3\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}x+2=y-5\\ \text{one of the previous two equations}\end{cases}$$ and then what?

Comment: Yep you didn't make interesting progress (in fact you get further away from solution) but at least equivalence is preserved and can go back.

Comment: I think this is a good question.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thank you! Can you please say what rule/assumption does not allow to drop the second equation?

Comment: @АнтонБугаев What does that mean? I'm only aware of rules that allow things to be done. You might as well take the fact that what you've done does not work as you expected as a theorem that says that what you've done doesn't do what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a substitution is logically correct. However, it is a conclusion and the result is a necessary condition that is no longer sufficient.
$$
(x,y)=(1,8)\Longleftrightarrow x+2=3 \text{ AND }y-5=3\;\Longrightarrow y-x=7 \not\Longrightarrow (x,y)=(1,8)
$$
Hence, the substitution gives more solutions than the two equations alone. $y-x=7$ is necessary for any solution of the two equations. However, it is no longer equivalent to both equations, i.e. we lost information.

Comment: Thank you! But what rule/assumption should I follow not to loose the information? Does the logic/math prevent us from doing the transition that I did?

Comment: There are various ways to approach it. One is the geometry. Both equations stand for a straight, and their intersection point is the solution. The difference between them is a new straight where the solution is just one point on that straight. I prefer an algebraic point of view and check every step whether it is reversible. Once you have $y-x=7$ there is no way back except you keep one of the original equations. You can write $y-x=7 \text{ AND }x+2=3$ and nothing is lost. However, nothing is gained either. A thrid possibility is where mathematics starts, linear algebra to be exact.

Comment: Linear algebra opens a variety of new tools that let you deal with straights, planes, 
etc. in arbitrary dimensions. Here we have two dimensions, x and y, and two lines $x=1$ and $y=8$ that intersect at $(x,y)=(1,8).$ Two such lines are either parallel, identical, or intersect at one point. In 3-dimensional space, there is a further possibility: skewness. 

The easiest way is to check whether a conclusion is reversible. This means in more complicated situations to check whether the solution you got is actually a solution. Here we have $x+2=3 \Rightarrow x=1$ and $x=1 \Rightarrow x+2=3$.